# Bean property 'firstName' is not readable or has an invalid getter method

Tags: spring

I have the below method in `ContactController` class file

```
public ModelAndView listContacts() { 
    return new ModelAndView("contact", "contact", contactService.listContact()); 
}
```

And I'm iterating this list in JSP:

```
<c:if test="${!empty contact}">
<table class="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${contact}" var="contact">
        <tr>
            <td>${contact.lastName}, ${contact.firstName}</td>
            <td>${contact.email}</td>
            <td>${contact.telephone}</td>
            <td><a href="delete/${contact.id}">delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'firstName' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'firstName' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you like making your own life difficult :-) Why are you using the same name for different things. You have a list of contacts, this list should be named `contacts` (plural form: it's a list of severa contacts), and not `contact`. And then in the loop, each individual contact can be named `contact` (singular form: it's a single Contact instance):

```
return new ModelAndView("contact", "contacts", contactService.listContact());

<c:forEach items="${contacts}" var="contact">
    <tr>
        <td>${contact.lastName}, ${contact.firstName}</td>
        <td>${contact.email}</td>
        <td>${contact.telephone}</td>
        <td><a href="delete/${contact.id}">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I made code chage as you said, But i am getting this error
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attribute

Comment: That means that you're still trying to use ${contact} outside of the forEach loop (in ${!empty contact}, form example), or inside the items attribute of the forEach loop.

Comment: <c:if test="${!empty contacts}"> <table class="data"> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Telephone</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> </tr> <c:forEach items="${contacts}" var="contact"> <tr> <td>${contact.lastName}, ${contact.firstName}</td> <td>${contact.email}</td> <td>${contact.telephone}</td> <td><a href="delete/${contact.id}">delete</a></td> </tr> </c:forEach> </table> </c:if>
I have changed as $(! empty contacts)

Comment: Edit your question, and show the full stack trace of the exception.